# How can I increase the y of a label, in swift?

Tags: swift, label, axes

So I am very new in Swift and I can't figure out how to increase the y value from a label.

I am trying to show in a label, some messages that a user types in an input... like a chat view.
So I have this code, but it puts all the messages one above the other:

I know that it is very messy, I am sorry for that. 
Thanks!

```
//my label
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    //my text field
    @IBOutlet weak var textF: UITextField!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        //create a variable(input) to store my text from the TextField
        var input = textF.text
        //put that text in the label
        label.text = input

        var label2 : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 21))
        var isSendMessage: Bool = true {
            didSet {
                if isSendMessage {
                    var input = textF.text
                    label.text = input
                    textF.text = " "
                  //  self.view.label.origin.y += 10

                } else {
                    var input = textF.text
                    label2.text = input
                    textF.text = " "

                }
            }
        }

        label2.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.view.addSubview(label2)

        //empty text field
        textF.text = " "

        label2.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label2.text = input

        //add it to the view
        self.view.addSubview(label2)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Don't update Y axis directly as if your Y value is greater than the screen height then label will go off the screen.

Try the following code.

```
// Taking height and width of the screen

var height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height;
var width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width; 
var x = 164.0 // Fixed height of the label

if x < height 
{
    x += 20.0  // Incrementing height value
    if (height - 20) >= x  // Checking the difference between screen height and x, so it doesn't go beyond the screen.
    {
       label.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, x, 200.0, 21.0)
       self.view.addSubview(label)
    }
    else
    {    
         // Setting default height
         label.frame = CGRectMake(20.0,164.0, 200.0, 21.0)
         self.view.addSubview(label)
    }

}
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering,  but don't you know a way that will let me increase these :  `label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 164, 200, 21)` ,  something like : `float x = 0; label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 164+x, 200, 21) ; x=x+10` ?  I know that I need to add a `for ` loop, but I can't find the syntax for this : `164+x` .

Comment: I get an error on "if x < height  "  :   " binary operator < cannot be applied to operands of type int and CGFloat " :(

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check does it solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

In a quick answer to your question, if you are just looking to change the position on the y-axis you can use the property .y under .center

```
self.yourLabel.center.y = self.yourLabel.center.y + 10
```